# Find position in while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a while loop in WordPress where by it outputs some custom field and post data. What I want to do is look inside the loop and check to find if a field matches to highlight the field and also output its position from the iteration.

My users have a field in their profile called 'schoolname' which I wan to reference against.

```
$user_info = get_userdata(1);

echo $user_info->schoolname; 

$i= 1;

$loop = new WP_Query( 
array( 'post_type' => 'schools', 
       'posts_per_page' => -1, 
       'orderby' => 'signups',
       'order'   => 'ASC', ) 
); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

echo '<tr>
      <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
      <td>' . get_the_title() . '</td>
      <td>' . $signups = get_field( "signups") . ' Signups</td>
      </tr>';

 endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: `$i` is your loop iteration position number. what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: So for instance, if I am logged in as a certain school and my schoolname field is 'test school' I can see that my school is say 5th in the loop I need to print out that schoolname is 5th.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I am looking essentially to marry up the schoolname field from my users profile and find which one it is in the loop and output the iteration number so its like a leaderboard, I want to find where in the leaderboard my school is and out that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the state of your loop you could also use a `foreach`

```
<?php global $post; // required

$posts = get_posts();
foreach($posts as $state => $post) : setup_postdata($post);
...
endforeach;
?>
```

You can replace the `while` part `with the foreach part. To know the iteration number just use`$state`.

#### Update

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'schools', 
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'orderby' => 'signups',
       'order'   => 'ASC',
));
?>

<?php if ($posts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $key => $post): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $key; ?></td>
            <td><?= get_the_title(); ?></td>
            <td><?= get_field( "signups"); ?> Signups</td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what dos this do exactly sorry? I am looking essentially to marry up the schoolname field from my users profile and find which one it is in the loop and output the iteration number so its like a leaderboard, I want to find where in the leaderboard my school is and out that number.

Comment: I am still struggling to fine out how to do this if you could kindly explain to me a little further?

Comment: so am I able to like lookup my school and then find its position in the loop?

Comment: You can compare `$post->schoolname` and `$user_data->schoolname`

Comment: How would I best go about comparing like inside of the loop or does it need to be done inside? I tried to do an equals with both of these and it just dosnt seem to match